# How to store a variable by using a method in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, boolean, try-catch, do-while

I have a few problems with the code below. I'm still learning and I don't know how to fix it.

1 .-What I'm trying to do is create a method (GetInt) to store variables like I'm trying to do in the second method (GetTrack) that will go into my main method.

2.-I can't get the GetInt method to loop when theres an invalid input, I'm guessing there's something wrong with the try/catch and boolean thingy

Thank you

```
//Get int Method
static public void GetInt(string sPrompt, int iMin, int iMax)
{
    int iNum;
    bool bError = false;

    do
    {
        bError = true;
        try
        {
            Console.Write(sPrompt);
            iNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if ((iNum < iMin) || (iNum > iMax))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The value is out of range.");
                bError = true;
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An invalid number was entered, please try again.");
            bError = true;
        }
    }
    while (bError == false);
}

//Get Track Method
static public void GetTrack()
{
    int iMin;
    int iSec;

    iMin = GetInt("Enter the minutes: ", 0, 10);
    iSec = GetInt("Enter the seconds: ", 0, 59);
}
```

Comment: do a quick Google Search on `void` and what void methods do.. in regards to `return values`

Comment: It might be slightly better that your `try` only wraps `iNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` so that you aren't catching (and ignoring) other exceptions. For example, if `sPrompt` is `null` then `Console.Write` will throw an exception, but your program will simply catch that exception and say "invalid number, try again" even though the number is valid, it's `sPrompt` that's invalid.

Answer (score 6):

Immediately in the beginning of `GetInt` you set `bError` to true. This most likely should be false so you would actually loop since nowhere do you set it to false.

Also you don't return anything from the method so you don't get anything back. You have to change the method to return `int` and actually return the value when you get it.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of your `GetInt` method should be changed to the following:

```
//Get int Method
static public int GetInt(string sPrompt, int iMin, int iMax)
```

Remove the `bError = true;` statement from the beginning of your do...while loop.
After your do...while loop, add the following statement:

```
return iNum;
```

Also, your `while` condition should be changed from `bError == false` to `bError == true` or simply to `bError`, which means the same thing, if your intent is to keep prompting the user until the input is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I "get" user input from the console:

```
            string choice = string.Empty;
            bool goodChoice = false;

            while (!goodChoice)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
                Console.WriteLine("Do you really want to hurt me?");
                Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
                Console.WriteLine("Please Y or N (or 0 to exit)");
                choice = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

                if (choice.Equals("Y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    goodChoice = true;
                }

                if (choice.Equals("N", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    goodChoice = true;
                }

                if (choice.Equals("0"))
                {
                    goodChoice = true;
                    return; /* exist the routine */
                }
            }
```

Modified for your case

```
            string choice = string.Empty;
            bool goodChoice = false;

            while (!goodChoice)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter an Integer between {0} and {1}", minValue, maxValue);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer (or X to exit)");
                choice = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

                int intParseResult = 0;
                bool intParseAttempt = int.TryParse(choice, out intParseResult);
                if(!intParseAttempt)
                {
                    goodChoice = false;
                }
                else
                {
                        if ((intParseResult < minValue) || (intParseResult > maxValue))
                        {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Out of Range");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            goodChoice = true;
                        }
                }

                if (choice.Equals("X"))
                {
                    goodChoice = true;
                    return -99999; /* you'll have to figure out how to handle exits on your own */
                }
            }
```

Comment: PS, please drop the Hungarian notation.  It went out with the Macarena.  (ex: iNum , iMax)